# Doorknob's Revenge

Tags: password

**Disclaimer:** I'll be using the gender-neutral pronoun "[xe](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/xe)" for the singular third person.

---

After escaping from [d'alar'cop's cellar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/14933/9000), Doorknob♦ was understandably upset. After almost two months of planning, xe gathered some support and the revenge scheme was enacted...

d'alar'cop awoke in a darkened room on a hard surface. Xe was sore from lying there for some unknown time. As soon as xe shifted xyr weight to stand up, lights came on all around the room. Blinking in the sudden brightness, xe took in xyr surroundings. Xe was on a raised daïs in the middle of a round room. A soft glow emanated from underneath and illuminated most of the room. There were 31 other puzzlers in the room, each in their own alcove. The recesses were painted a variety of colors and even the daïs was painted blue. Each puzzler was either staring at d'alar'cop or facing directly away. In front of each puzzler was a set of two lights that was facing the daïs, facing the alcove, or turned off. (AJ Henderson was staring directly into two powerful lights blasting into xyr face. Ow.) Just as d'alar'cop had finished taking this all in, all 31 puzzlers began to chant in unison:

> You've been naughty, kidnapper
> Taking prisoners, doing wrong
> Now it's time for you to learn
> If you're mean, you will get burned
>
> You are trapped here in this room
> From that daïs you may not move
> You must solve our riddle soon
> Or from our pack you will be hewn
>
> The door at south is your escape
> But it shan't open lest you say
> The secret message known to us
> Speaking quickly is a plus
>
> Poison daggers now descend
> From ceiling to your flesh to pierce
> They will slow your very breath
> Bringing soon a painful death
>
> If you belong then you will see
> An answer not quite seen by thee
> Although mad we are not cruel
> We shall grant a single tool
>
> You have a laptop, internet
> Seek the answer on the web
> Careful, though, where you tread
> There are tricks and traps ahead

d'alar'cop's eyes adjusted to the light during the chant and xe could see the laptop. Thankfully, it's already booted up and xyr favorite browser was open to a blank tab. With a quick glance upward at the glistening blades, xe set to work as the puzzlers started up their chant again.

### How can d'alar'cop find the password?

---

Diagram of the room: (The diagram was made in Excel. Any minor errors in position or orientation are not part of the puzzle.)

[image: Diagram of the Room]

Puzzler Positions:

1:  [Rainbolt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/74/rainbolt)
2:  [Andrea](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/69/andrea)
3:  [RBerteig](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/84/rberteig)
4:  [zar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/32/zar)
5:  [mau](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70/mau)
6:  [SztupY](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/85/sztupy)
7:  [Hubble07](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/101/hubble07)
8:  [senshin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/76/senshin)
9:  [The Wobbuffet](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/95/the-wobbuffet)
10: [Adele C](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/67/adele-c)
11: [AJ Henderson](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/65/aj-henderson)
12: [user88377](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/78/user88377)
13: [Doorknob♦](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/39/doorknob)
14: [gsingh2011](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/116/gsingh2011)
15: [bluefeet♦](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/45/bluefeet)
16: [Robert Cartaino♦](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/77/robert-cartaino)
17: [Raystafarian](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51/raystafarian)
18: [vivekpoddar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/108/vivekpoddar)
19: [glenneroo](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/43/glenneroo)
20: [James Jenkins](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/126/james-jenkins)
21: [Young Guilo](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/83/young-guilo)
22: [CaffeinePwrdAl](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/197/caffeinepwrdal)
23: [DaG](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/144/dag)
24: [crownjewel82](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/130/crownjewel82)
25: [Piero Alberto](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/124/piero-alberto)
26: [Michal](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/255/michal)
27: [Danubian Sailor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/66/danubian-sailor)
28: [Crispy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/138/crispy)
29: [Gilles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/97/gilles)
30: [strikers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/109/strikers)
31: [igelkott](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/115/igelkott)
32: [d'alar'cop](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2484/dalarcop)

---

### FOUND MESSAGES

Trap Level 1 found by [Sebu](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/17585/9000) (+1)
Trap Level 2 not yet found
Trap Level 3 not yet found
Password found by [Shawn Holzworth](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/17598/9000) (Tick after another day or two to keep it active so maybe people will try to find the remaining traps)

Comment: I don't understand why using "Xe" if both d'alar'cop and Doorknob are males.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Because I didn't know their genders.

Comment: I'm leery of the profile links. Puzzles aren't supposed to rely on changeable information, and the only information on a SE user's profile page that *isn't* changeable is his/her user name, which obviates the needs for links. Is this puzzle still going to be valid 3 months, 6 months, or 1 year from now?

Comment: @COTO I suspect it's the user IDs (Rainbolt 74, Doorknoob 39, and so on), which are even _less_ changeable than the usernames.

Comment: @randal'thor: Ah. Carry on then.

Comment: So, according to this post, moderators have the ability to suspend users, cast binding votes, search for deleted posts, kidnap members, and remove bounties (among other powers)? Very informative!

Comment: Where does it explain the clues for trap level 2 and 3?

Comment: @PythonMaster There aren't really clues for the trap levels. They're just more hidden messages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well what do you know, it seems rand al'thor was on to something:

> When you take the user id numbers for users 1-31 as ascii, you get a message:
> JET Fuel_CAN't-m3l+~S┼Éé| Bèams

Comment: @mmking I think it's fun and the point is to write better puzzles, right? It doesn't matter what you're hiding; the interesting bit is *how* you're hiding it.

Comment: Oh great, so now I can be afraid to be part of any puzzle, as my user ID translates to "U"

Answer (score 7):

Transform the colours into numbers by

> using their RGB codes: red is 100, green is 010, blue is 001, cyan is 011, magenta is 101, yellow (not used) is 110, white is 111, black (not used) is 000.

Then going round from 1 all the way to 32, we get the code:

> 010 100 100 100 010 101 111 100 001 111 111 100 100 001 111 101 010 100 100 101 001 001 001 001 010 011 100 100 011 100 100 001

Change the spacing to get:

> 01010010 01000101 01111100 00111111 11001000 01111101 01010010 01010010 01001001 01001110 01000111 00100001

which we can convert using

> ASCII code

to get

> RE|?È}RRING!

So Trap Level 2 is a red herring!

Comment: RE|?È}RRING! - You set off the alarm!

Comment: This was actually Trap #3 because it involved more steps. It shall receive the +100 bounty once it's able to be rewarded.

Answer (score 6):

At least I got the first trap:

> Morse code, with light toward 32 as - and away from 32 as . read from 1 to 31 gives "Don't give up, try again" with a little Formating on my Part.

And I will try again :-D

Answer (score 5):

And I've found Trap Level 3 as well! :-D

Look at the numbers 1-32. You need to look inwards to read some of them and outwards to read others. Let's use 1 and 0 respectively to denote these two types of number. Let's also assume (since it gives the right answer) that 32 is towards the top rather than the bottom, so that it's 0 rather than 1. Then the numbers 1-32 give the code 01001110010011110101000001000101.

> Space it out as 01001110 01001111 01010000 01000101 and use ASCII code *again*

to get

> NOPE.

So we've found a 3rd red herring, and the final answer (or Trap Level 4) is the message found by Shawn Holzworth.

Comment: This was actually Trap #2 because it involved less steps. It shall receive the +50 bounty once it's able to be rewarded.