# Uh, I'm kinda stuck. Help?

Tags: steganography

Heck. I'm stuck, trapped in this cedar madness.
Ash to dust. I'm doomed. I'll fall and look like ketchup. 
Anyone, please save me. I want out of this tree, maybe I'll go get a cuppa.
Literally anyone. I think this is a chestnut. Save me, I'll and buy you some liquor?
Perfect I'm falling. Holly heck there's no justice!

> What did I say, as I fell? 
>   For the love of God, **PLEASE ______ ME!**

Comment: Please do not edit the last line of the question; it changes the author's intent.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Seems almost trivial, but...

> The last letters of each line, taken in order, spell SPARE. Which fits the final question. So, you are saying as you fall, "PLEASE SPARE ME!"

Just saw another possibility:

> Each line contains the name of a tree: Cedar, Ash, Tree (haha, very funny), Chestnut, and Holly. The first letters of these spell out CATCH, which also fits! "PLEASE CATCH ME!"

Comment: I think your second one is more realistic. I too noticed the trees, but couldn't string it together meaningfully.

Comment: Dang! I was half way through typing "nope" to your first answer. But your second guessed hit the nail on the head. Congratz!

Comment: @Asteria: thanks, but I wouldn't award the green tick so soon just so the rest of the community has time to try their hand at this too. And nice puzzle, by the way!

Comment: @Xenocacia thank you! And that's fair, I'll wait a bit next time! Thank you for the advice :)

Comment: I thought my guess was too simple. @Asteria nice puzzle, love that there are 3 answers in 1

Comment: I also thought the second answer, but for different reasons. I saw the tree names, I saw "Ash... Ketchup" and immediately thought of Pokemon, so that seemed appropriate here.

Comment: @QBrute haha! I didn't make that connection, but I love it :D

Comment: Could line 3 be “tea”?  “Tree” isn’t very satisfying.

Answer (score 7):

Please

> HAALP

Meeeee!

> As spelled out by the first letter of each line. Initially thought the steganography tag was a mistake but it was not!

Comment: Oh damn, identical answer separated by a few seconds.

Answer (score 6):

Did you say...

> For the love of God, please HAALP me!

Since the

> Initial letters of the 5 sentences spell our HAALP, which sounds like "help" when shouted :-)

Comment: Good guess! but there's a total of 3 "traps" hidden ;) that's number 1

Comment: “Traps” that feel like perfectly valid answers don’t make a good puzzle :(

Comment: Interesting riddle. Which is the final trap?

Comment: @Timwi It's like in the SATs - there might be some valid-looking answers, but the right answer is the "most correct" one.

Comment: @Timwi "Traps" [can be done well](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/17550/5373), in such a way that it's very clear which answer is the 'correct'/intended one.